# Вопрос про наведение и замену картинки

Tags: html, style

Добрый день. Использую данный код. Но не выходит отобразить вторую картинку при наведение мышки.

```
<style>
#RollOver1 a .hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#RollOver1 a img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-width: 0;
}
#RollOver1 img {
    border-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
</style>
<div id="RollOver1" style="position:relative;left:580px;top:-10px;overflow:hidden;width:64px;height:71px;z-index:18;">
<a href="http://broker-sb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Protivodeistvie_korrupcii.pdf" target="_blank">
<img class="hover" alt="" src="http://broker-sb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/doc3.png"/>
<span><img alt="" src="http://broker-sb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/doc1.png"/></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Где может быть ошибка? Брал пример с другого сайта...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решил вашу задачу иным способом:

```css
  .img {
      display:block;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      background:url(http://broker-sb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/doc1.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat
      
   }
   .img:hover {
      background:url(http://broker-sb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/doc3.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat
   }
```

```html
<a class="img" target="_blank" href="http://broker-sb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Protivodeistvie_korrupcii.pdf"></a>
```